# What are all the requirements for replacement application icons for windows phone 7 apps?

Tags: windows-phone-7, icons

I'm trying to create new icons for my windows phone 7 app. Whenever I run the app I get the default icons. This has been my process.

1. I created a 200 px x 200 px icon in photoshop.
2. I exported 62 px, 99 px and 173 px square versions as PNG files.
3. I copied these to the images folder in my project and then ADDed them as existing files in Visual Studio 2010.
4. I selected each image and changed their properties to "Content" and "Copy Always".
5. I right-clicked properties and selected the appropriate icons for Icon and BackgroundImage.
6. Cleaned the solution and uninstalled previous installations from the phone.
7. Rebuilt the project and checked the WMAppManifest.xml to be sure the proper PNGs were listed.
8. I redeploy the app and the default icons continue to show in the emulator and the device when either type of deploy is tried.

Any suggestions as to what I'm missing?

Comment: Step 3 is wrong. Don't copy to the images folder, leave in root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The art files you add to your project need to be in the root directory of your project with your App.xaml. At least this is what fixed it for me. When I added the new art to the images directory they showed up in the properties panel and I could select them. However they did not get used when deployed. I did try changing the path manually in the manifest but that didn't work (or I typed it wrong). Moving the icon art to the root fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

There are three images that are automatically added in your WP7 project - `ApplicationIcon.png, Background.png and SplashScreenImage.jpg`. These are the three images you need to change (directly, not a copy). The names are important as well, since WP7 will look for those filenames in particular.

`ApplicationIcon.png` is the small tile you see when you slide to the right of your home screen and see the list of apps.

`Background.png` is the tile that gets shown when pinned to your homescreen.

`SplashScreen.jpg` is the splash screen that gets shown when your app is first launched.

The 200x200 (and other image sizes you created) don't have to be part of the application itself. They're used for your Marketplace submission. Depending on how the user is browsing the marketplace, the relevant sized tile will be shown. You don't need to include those in the XAP as you'll be asked to upload them when you submit your app. Only the three files mentioned at the beginning need to be in the XAP.